# Apache mod_rewrite and Tomcat digest authentication

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I have a webapp deployed in Tomcat server with Apache in front of it. One of the requirements, is that the webapp has to be accessible using two different paths. For example:

```
http://domain.com/aa/bb/v1/*
and
http://domain.com/cc/v1/*
```

My webapp is configured with the first URL, so any request to /aa/bb/v1/* is handled correctly by Tomcat.

Then, to be able to "forward" the calls to the second URL to the first one, I've used mod_rewrite in apache, like this:

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule /aa/bb/v1/(.+)  cc/v1/$1  [NC,L,P]
```

This works fine! Except when I activate the digest authentication in Tomcat. In digest, the password sent by the browser is some more or less complex hash value calculated including the username, the realm and among other things, the URI. The URI of the browser, is not the URI of the webapp (I've modified it with mod_rewrite) so the authentication fails.

Any ideas in how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found one easy solution. One of the configurable values of the Tomcat's Digest valve is to do not validate URIs. This can be done by adding the digest valve configuration in the context.xml file:

```
    <Context>

        <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
        <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.DigestAuthenticator" validateUri="false" />
......
```

I'm not sure if somebody will say that this is insecure... however, for my case is enough.